# Windows phone silverlight 8.1 app certification fail

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am trying to submit my windows phone silverlight 8.1 app to the store but app fails certification within few seconds after submitted to the store.I don't think they can test app this much faster so must be some kind of problem with the server. Only error is "This submission failed certification.". I have tried it so many times but no success but I can update my windows phone 8 apps I previously uploaded.  Any solutions? thank you

Comment: If an app fails certification, you get a report from dev center with the details of the reason due to which certification failed. Please check that and post the error message.

Comment: I didn't get any report, only error message: "This submission failed certification" . In my previous apps I did get error report and I fixed errors and submitted apps but this time only one error, no other information

Comment: If you are sure, there is no report contact dev center support [here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/community/windows-app-support)

Comment: I have contacted them, they are taking so much time to respond

Comment: Chat with them rather than sending email. They have limited chat hours but they respond promptly via chat.

Comment: I am doing both, it's been 4 days, still waiting

Comment: @thewarri0r9 Share your store fail error print screenshot then get some idea on that.